# Форум на JSP и MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jsp

Нужно написать форум с помощью JSP и базы данных MongoDB. Посоветуйте, как лучше поступить, создать одну коллекцию для всего форума и работать с ней, или несколько коллекций? Для разделов, тем, и ответов для тем.
Может есть другие идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!
Это будет зависеть от функционала который Вы захотите реализовать на Вашем форуме.

Пример:
    На форуме, должны присутствовать пользоваели, следовательно болжна быть таблица (коллекция) пользователей с данными по ним. Пользователи моут оставлять сообщения - будет и таблица сообщений и т.д.
    Конешн, я не оч силен в NoSql  решениях, но я думаю что аналогия понятна)

Answer (score 1):

Тут главное сесть и на листочке выписать:

1. какие типы контента будут (пользователи, новости, пост форума, комментарии)
2. какие из них будут использоваться отдельно

Поскольку каждый созданный документ будет получать свой **_id**, который будет индексироваться, а чем больше индексов - тем больше размер базы и время поиска(хотя и дело идет о миллисекундах, но все же), то нужно разграничить контент на тот который нуждается в _id и на тот который нет.

Например: в MySQL комментарий будет лежать в отдельной таблице. В монге можно также создать коллекцию "db.comments", где каждый коммент получит _id за который мы его и будем вытягивать. А можно просто его засунуть в сам пост, ведь этот тип контента нигде больше использоваться не будет.

```
forum_post: {
  title: "Название поста",
  body: "Lorem Ipsum",
  comments:[
      {author: "Ivan", 
       body: "comment"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть другая идея. Не использовать для форума mongo. В этом нет смысла.